# how users can pass twitter/linkedin credentials in my app?

Tags: c#, twitter, linkedin-api

i know that developers have to register an email and their application with `twitter or linkedin` to get the respective api's up.

the situation I am facing is this. I need each client using my application to supply their username/password credentials(twitter / linked in credentials depending on page) using `oauth` the first time they are visiting a page associated with linkedin or twitter.for example an user may need to reply/retweet to tweets.

The `oauth` modules I see supply consumer key and such input.

what is the best way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

Users of your application are not required to provide their Twitter credentials in order to access Twitter through your application; this is one of the points of OAuth.  Your users are required to log into Twitter and authorize your application to access their account.

It's no longer possible for a third-party application to access a user's Twitter account using their Twitter credentials.  This was called "Basic Auth" and it was phased out in 2010.

The relevant documentation is here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/using-oauth

Answer (score 0):

used hammock for both linkedin and twitter oauth before using tweetsharp..nokia site had valuable samples